# Using cucumber with ruby and Netbeans

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

I am using Cucumber netbeans plugin  Cetriolo, I have created a .feature file for Login feature scenario, and login_steps.rb for my steps definition but the problem is I cannot find a way to connect the feature with its steps any one has any idea about this plugin.

Comment: show a screenshot of what you have already.

Comment: http://imgbox.com/cD1qmgeq

Comment: the problem is with link the feature with its steps definitions